# Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzd,, Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present:

Tags: android

I am getting this error again and again tried to do all the things said by the users on other posts of stack flow but the problem still persists.

below is the screenshot of grade file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJmYK.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iilD6.jpg)

and the error that I am getting is :

> Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzd Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present:
>   com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzd, sources=[Unknown source file],
>   tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

below is the screenshot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3TSX.jpg)

it would be great if anyone can help. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase did an update to the SDK:

> Firebase Android SDKs now have independent version numbers, allowing
>   for more frequent, flexible updates.

Update all your Firebase dependencies to use the latest version:

```
Firebase Core           com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3
Ads                     com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.0
Analytics               com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.3
App Indexing            com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:16.0.1
Authentication          com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3
Cloud Firestore         com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.0
Cloud Functions         com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:16.1.0
Cloud Messaging         com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.1
Cloud Storage           com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.2
Crash Reporting         com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.0
Crashlytics             com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5
Invites                 com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.3
Performance Monitoring  com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.1.0
Realtime Database       com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.2
Remote Config           com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0
```

Please also update google-services plugin:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.1'
```

Comment: Above mentioned SDK versions are out dated. Latest version of firebase core is 16.0.3!! Have you checked into Firebase Release Notes page before posting the answer? [Have a look Firebase Release Notes Page](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android)